# Arrays in `AGGREGATE` and `INDEX` functions

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365

### The Scenario:

So, today at work my computer ran an MS Office update.  Then, about 30 minutes later someone came up to me with what seemed like a simple request:  Instead of using a `VLOOKUP` to return just the *first* match, they wanted a delimited list of **all** matches. (e.g. "which offices has this user visited this week"?)  Seemed simple enough.

So, working with some junk data (see below), I swiftly wrote the following quick demonstration line:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$11, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:A$11)/--(A$1:A$11=E1), ROW(A$1:A$11))),""))
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and...  `6`.  Not quite what I was expecting (`6, 35, 19, 56, 47`), so I say "sorry about that", go back into the cell, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`6`, again.

So, ran the "Evaluate Formula", and it turns out that that `ROW(A$1:A$11)` in the *k* position (last argument) of `AGGREGATE` was returning `1` instead of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}`, regardless of whether or not you were using a normal or Array formula.

So, I type the array out manually:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$11, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:A$11)/--(A$1:A$11=E1), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11})),""))
```

End result:  `6`.  I Evaluate Formula again, and `AGGREGATE` is discarding everything except the first value from my array.  If I drop the `INDEX`, and just run `TEXTJOIN` on the `AGGREGATE` results, it works fine.  Similarly, `=SUM(ROW(B1:B11))` works fine, but `=SUM(INDEX(B1:B11, ROW(B1:B11), 1))` does not.

### The Question:

Now, I am **95% sure** that I used to be able to get this `INDEX(.., AGGREGATE(..))` and `SUM(INDEX(..))` to work properly, instead of only returning the first value - is this something that haschanged about how certain chains of functions work with Arrays, or am I just misremembering?

(For those interested, in the end we went with the Array Formula `=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(A$1:A$11=E1, B$1:B$11, ""))` instead)

Junk data used in testing:

```
A |  6
A | 35
A | 19
B | 33
B | 46
B | 72
A | 56
C | 41
C | 20
B | 52
A | 47
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though as you have found adding the IF instead of the long INDEX/AGGREGATE works.

The reason it did not work is that INDEX is not normally set up to take an array as the row number.

But we can force it to using `N(IF({1},...))`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$11, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:A$11)/--(A$1:A$11=E1), N(IF({1},ROW(A$1:A$11))))),""))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

[image]

But again this is the long way around when a simple `IF()` will do what is needed.

Comment: Sir this something new I have learnt we can use an `IF()` for the `sth` value `N(IF({1},ROW(A$1:A$11))))),"")` nice trick sir